# get column data and store into array VB6

Tags: vb6

How to loop the column field and insert to Array

```
 Do While rstRGRPT1.RecordCount
                sCol = rstRGRPT1!FCOL
                'oAList.Add "sCol"
                rstRGRPT1.MoveNext
            Loop
```

Comment: "loop the column field"? Do you mean "iterate through the field objects of the recordset and copy them into an array"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Dim numbers(50) As Integer
Dim i as integer
i=0
     Do While not rstRGRPT1.EOF
                    numbers(i)=rstRGRPT1.fields(0)
                    rstRGRPT1.MoveNext
                    i=i+1
                Loop
```

Comment: thx for ur reply, 

after i get the fields, how to insert into array ? 

ReDim Preserve sFieldArray(UBound(sFieldArray) + 1)
            
            
  sFieldArray(sFieldArray(i)) = rstRGRPT1!RPT_CODE

i no have idea to do it..because the data i want export to excel one

thanks for help !